# Why is my match success false?

Tags: c#, regex

Why is my match success equal to false? I have tested the below pattern and input in Regexbuddy and it is successful.

```
string pattern = @"(?i)(<!-- START -->)(.*?)(?i)(<!-- END -->)";
string input = @"Hello
    <!-- START -->
    is there anyone out there?
    <!-- END -->";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (match.Success) //-- FALSE!
{
    string found = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(found);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure .NET accepts that syntax for case ignoring?

Comment: The first `(?i)` makes everything after it case-insensitive, so the second one isn't doing anything useful.  If you want to limit its effect, you can use this form: `(?i:<!-- START -->)`.  There's no need in this case though, since `START` and `END` are the only things it affects anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this out**

```
string pattern = @"(?is)(<!-- START -->)(.*?)(<!-- END -->)";
string input = @"Hello
    <!-- START -->
    is there anyone out there?
    <!-- END -->";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.None);
if (match.Success) //-- FALSE!
{
    string found = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(found);
}
```

**using `s` option forces your pattern to match `.` any character including `\r` and `\n`.**

Answer (score 3):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx

The `RegexOptions.Multiline` causes `^` and `$` to change their meaning so they will match on any line of the input. It does not cause `.` to match `\n`. For that, you need to use `RegexOptions.Singleline`

Answer (score 0):

Use single line option

```
Regex RegexObj = new Regex("(?i)(<!-- START -->)(.*?)(?i)(<!-- END -->)",
        RegexOptions.Singleline);
```